# JavaFX Fade Transition issue

Tags: java, javafx

I followed every instruction I could find, tried various ways to implement this, always with the same symptom: Nothing happens...

Expectation:
Have an image that is fading from 100% transparent to 0% transparent.

I have this FadingImage class:

```
public class FadingImage{

    private FadeTransition ft;

    public FadingImage(String imgName,int posX, int posY, double from, double to, Group root) {
        ImageView img = new ImageView(imgName);
        ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1000));

        ft.setNode(img);

        ft.setFromValue(from); //sets the start opacity value
        ft.setToValue(to); //sets the target opacity value
        ft.setCycleCount(1);
        ft.setAutoReverse(false);

        img.setTranslateX(posX);
        img.setTranslateY(posY);
        root.getChildren().add(img);
    }

    public void play(){
        ft.playFromStart();
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
FadingImage fi = new FadingImage("images/dock1.png",500, 500, 0.0, 1.0, root);
fi.play();
```

I am getting no exceptions whatsoever.
If I add a System out in the play method, it shows it.

I feel like I am missing something basic here, I just don't find it...

Comment: Help is much appreciated...

Comment: What is your expectation (from your code i.e.)?

Comment: Added to OP: Have an image that is fading from 100% transparent to 0% transparent.

Comment: What do you mean 'nothing happens'? Do you not get an image?

Comment: No, an image does not appear.

Comment: Do you get an image if you remove the transition?

Comment: I did it... As I thought... Basic mistake... The image appeared outside my window...

Comment: This code can be useful for others, so I won't delete this post

Comment: @WilhelmSorban In general, on this site, don't delete questions unless they're of exceptionally low quality please.

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer. It's not going to be a particularly useful answer, but still better than editing your question to add non-question stuff (answering your own questions is perfectly legal).

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Animation/Transitions/Fade%20Transition)? PS: I'm sorry, I cannot comment yet...

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. The parameters used were incorrect, as the image was displayed outside the screen.